# How can I set up short forms for commands on Unix shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

If some frequently used commands in Unix shell are given short forms, it reduces programmer's effort.

example :

How can I use e instead of "emacs -nw".

Comment: Type `help alias` as short introduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create command aliases. Open the `~/.bashrc` file and add this line:

```
alias e='emacs -nw'
```

Then re-load it to apply changes:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

In your .bashrc in your home directory add

`alias e='emacs -nw'`

to the end of the file. Either source the .bashrc file or open a new terminal to see the effects.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't already aware of aliases, skip them and move straight to shell functions:

```
e () {
    emacs -nw "$@"
}
```